# Resharper. How to run the same NUnit TestFixture class in parallel?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nunit, resharper

Has anybody implemented this yet? If I declare `[TestFixture]` class with `[Parallelizable]` attribute, I'm unable to run this single test class in parallel with multiple browser instances (Selenium). Added up to 4 assemblies in Resharper -> Options -> Unit Testing, didn't help. However, if I have several different test classes with `[Parallelizable]` attribute, they run in parallel as expected in R# unit test console. Any important point am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question lacks some details, so I'm assuming you have something like...

```
[Parallelizable]
[TestFixture("browser1")]
[TestFixture("browser2")]
[TestFixture("browser3")]
public class MyTestClass
{
    public MyTestClass(string browserName) { ... }
    ...
}
```

This creates a structure of tests like this...

```
MyTestClass
    MyTestClass("browser1")
    MyTestClass("browser2")
    MyTestClass("browser3")
```

That is, you get a test suite containing three fixture instances. Each fixture, of course, contains in turn whatever tests you have written.

The `[Parallelizable]` attribute applies to the suite, not to the individual tests. The suite is able to run in parallel with other parallelizable suites, fixtures and tests. But the individual fixtures in the suite are not parallelizable.

In my example, I can make the individual fixtures parallelizable by using `[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)]`. That says "From this point downward, you can parallelize fixtures."

Admittedly, this is quite an obscure point. We should figure out a way to make it clearer.

Anyway... if I guessed right, I think I answered your question. If I didn't, perhaps you could edit it so we have a better shot at helping.

Comment: To be more detailed: I have 
[TestFixture]
[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)]
public class SomeTest(){
[OneTimeSetUp]
public void setupMethod(){
//some code here
}
[Test]
public void initialTest(){
//some code here
}
[OneTimeTearDown]
public void tearDownMethod(){
//some code here
}

Comment: The question is if we can declare how many times SomeTest class will run in parallel. Something like [Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures) = 3] or [Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures) = 5]

Comment: If you are using `[TestFixture]` without arguments, you don't have a parameterized test fixture, so it will be instantiated and executed only once. The Parallelizable attribute has nothing to do with creating instances, only with whether they run in parallel. The syntax you want doesn't exist. You should edit your original question to show some code, since it's pretty illegible in a comment, and maybe we can try a different answer.